# Can I change Data Annottion at Runtime based on the type of storedprocedure I am calling

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, data-annotations

Hi my Entity is ParameterDetail as follows:

```
public class ParameterDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //..other columns removed for brevity
    public int LookupValueId { get; set; }
}
```

I call my stored procedure and load the results as follows...

```
        List<ParameterDetail> paramDetails = this.ParameterDetails.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.GE_GetStartParameter @GuidelineName={0}", guidelineName).ToList();
```

Now this all is working fine but now I have to call a slightly different procedure which does not have LookupValueId..

```
List<ParameterDetail> paramDetails =this.ParameterDetails.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.GetParameterDetails @ParameterId={0}", nextParam).ToList();
```

I don't want to add another EntityModel just for this one column....
Can i use Mapped property (Data Annotation) at runtime somehow? Or could there be any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i use Mapped property (Data Annotation) at runtime somehow? Or could there be any other solution?

Not if you want EF to perform the mapping, at least not a good one.  You can't change the attributes at runtime, but if you use Fluent configuration you could have two *different* DbContext subtypes that configure the same entity class differently.  But that's not a very elegant solution.

You can always just execute the stored procedure with ADO.NET and map the data however you want.